Add adjacency matrix in Voronoi
The data x and y represent the geographic coordinates of the centroids of cities 1 to 8:
> df <- data.frame(
+   ID = 1:8,
+   x = c(4.0, 7.0, 2.5, 8.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0),
+   y = c(8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1)
+ )
> df
  ID   x y
1  1 4.0 8
2  2 7.0 9
3  3 2.5 4
4  4 8.0 5
5  5 3.0 2
6  6 5.0 2
7  7 6.0 3
8  8 7.0 1

adj_matrix refers to the matrix of adjacencies of cities:
> adj_matrix <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
+                        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
+                        1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
+                        0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 8, byrow = TRUE)
> adj_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1
[6,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1
[7,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

Voronoi script to make the figure:
library(sp)
library(deldir)

x=data.frame(x=df$x,y=df$y) 
crds=x 
center=colMeans(crds) 
bb=c(center[1]-5,center[1]+5,center[2]-5,center[2]+5) 
z=deldir(x=crds[,1],y=crds[,2],rw=bb) 
w=tile.list(z) 
polys=vector(mode='list',length=length(w)) 
for (i in seq(along=polys)){
  pcrds=cbind(w[[i]]$x,w[[i]]$y)
  pcrds=rbind(pcrds,pcrds[1,])
  polys[[i]]=Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)),ID=as.character(i)) 
} 
SP = SpatialPolygons(polys) 
voronoi = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
  SP, 
  data = data.frame(
    Regiao_ID = as.character(1:dim(df)[1]), 
    x = crds[,1], 
    y = crds[,2], 
    row.names = sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))
  )
)


but the correct thing would be for regions 1 and 6 to border.
How to do this?
It can be in R, Python or another.

How do you anticipate 1 and 6 to border when 3 and 7 also have a border relationship in adj_matrix? I might be misinterpreting the method, but it appears to me that these pairs are mutually exclusive e.g. you can have one or the other, but not both. Also, in your matrix, you have 5, 6, and 7 bordering themselves. Is this correct?

Yes, it's true, but the main idea is to create a map from the centroid coordinates and an adjacency matrix.
I didn't find a method that did this, so the alternative was to use the Voronoi diagram, but any other solution is valid!
